# How do I draw the signal on the screen after the convulsion of discrete-time signals is calculated with java?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, signals

[I have written this mathematical expression in java, but I am having trouble charting it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4AAK.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SNTm.png)I want to write the code that calculates the convulsion of 2 different discrete-time signals and draws the result signal to the screen.I wrote the code that did this calculation. But I'm having trouble getting it on the screen.Can help in this regard?If I'm wrong with the coding, can you let me know?I wish you a good day.

```
 public static void KonHesap(double xSinyali,double hSinyali){ //double []x,double[]h
     //y[n] =Toplam sembolü k=-sonsuz dan  k=sonsuza  kadar  x(k).h(n-k) 
    double [] xSinyal=new double[10];
    double [] hSinyal=new double[10];
    int xLen=xSinyal.length;
    int hLen=hSinyal.length;
    double [] ySinyal=new double[xLen+hLen];


    //x sinyali
    for(int i=0;i<xLen;i++){

        xSinyal[i]=(double)(Math.random()*10);
        System.out.println("xSinyali["+i +"]"+ "= " + xSinyal[i]);
    }
    //h sinyali
    for(int j=-2;j<hLen;j++){

        hSinyal[j]=(double)(Math.random()*10);
        System.out.println("hSinyali[" +j+"]" + "= " +hSinyal[j]);
    }
   //h sinyali tersi için j yi "-" ile çarpacağız yani
    for(int j=-2;j<hLen;j++){
        hSinyal[-j]=(double)(Math.random()*20);
        System.out.println("hSinyali[" +j+"]" + "= " +hSinyal[j]);
    }
    //y sintali hespalanması yani konvulusyon al

    for(int i=xLen;i>0;i--){
        for(int j=-2;j<hLen;j++){
             ySinyal[j+(xLen-i)]+=hSinyal[j]*xSinyal[i];

        }
    }


}
```

public class KonvulusyonOdev extends javax.swing.JFrame {

```
public KonvulusyonOdev() {
    initComponents();
}
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponents(g);
     Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;



     jPanel1.setBackground(java.awt.Color.gray); // y sinyali panel rengi



}
```

Comment: You need to decide on a GUI (Graphical User Interface). I would suggest either JavaFX or Processing.

Comment: I'm already using the GUI and I want to plotter the resulting result to jpanel.This code is just the code I wrote to do the calculation.

Comment: May I suggest that you edit your question to reflect this? You question seems to be about drawing and you have no drawing code in your question, nor do you state your GUI. There is a tag for Swing.

Comment: can you add some examples for the input values ?

Comment: You might want to google "Java graphing in swing". This search brought up a few possibilities, including JFreeChart.

Comment: I think you mean convolution.  Convulsions are what you get if you drink too much.

Comment: I have written this mathematical expression in java, but I am having trouble charting it.

Comment: 1) don't invoke paintComponents(…) directly. Swing will invoke the method as required. 2) don't override paint() on a JFrame. Custom painting is done by overriding paintComponent(…) on a JPanel and then you add the panel to the frame. You would then invoke super.paintComponent(…) as the first statement. 3) don't change a property of your class in the painting method. The background color should be set in the constructor or in an external class. 4) I have no idea what those calculations do, but that logic should be part of the custom panel class that does the painting.